# Unable to refresh b-table component without resetting the pagination?

Tags: vue.js, buefy

I know i have asked this before but i dint get a reply to the previous question.I am currently using the Vue.js framework along with buefy (0.9.2) for the UI components.The issue here is that the b-table component is not updating sometimes on the page/ui when I click the delete icon(deletes that row from the table) or when I click the add new row button. I can confirm that the operations(delete and add row) themselves are working perfectly.(I verified this using a console log and also by inspecting the vuex store.Its just that the change is not reflecting in the page/ui.

Template example-

```
<b-table
      ref="records"
      :data="this.objectData.records"
      :hoverable="true"
      :paginated="true"
      :per-page="10"
      selectable
      @select="selected"
      detailed
      :show-detail-icon="true"
      icon-pack="mdi"
      custom-row-key="id"
    >  
  <b-table-column   v-slot="props" field="effectiveDate" label="Eff Date">{{ props.row.effectiveDate }}</b-table-column>
        <b-table-column   v-slot="props" field="jobType" label="Job Type">{{ props.row.jobType }}</b-table-column>
        <b-table-column   v-slot="props" field="action" label="Action">{{ props.row.action }}</b-table-column>   
        <b-table-column   v-slot="props">
          <b-button class="is-borderless is-borderless" @click="deleteTableRow('records','records',props.index)">
            <b-icon icon="delete"></b-icon>
          </b-button>        
        </b-table-column>
```

function that performs the delete row operation operation-

```
deleteTableRow(tableRef, dataCol, index) {
                this.objectData[dataCol].splice(index, 1);   
            },
```

NOTE: I have also tried using a key prop and incrementing this key in the delete row function to force refresh the b-table component,but the issue here is that it resets the pagination back to the 1st page.So what should I do in order to refresh the b-table component without re-setting the pagination back to the 1st page?

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to figure this out too. Re-fetching the whole list again just to update the pagination is overkill.